# pass a string variable into a gql query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

How in the world do I pass a string variable into GQL with python?? I can do it fine in SQL but it just isn't working.  here is what I have:

```
personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from PersonalPost where user_id = %s order by created desc limit 30" % user_id)
```

This has been killing me but should be really simple I feel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from PersonalPost where user_id =:1 order by created desc limit 30",user_id)
```

`GqlQuery` syntax examples:

```
q = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Song WHERE composer = 'Lennon, John'")

q = GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Song WHERE composer = :1", "Lennon, John")

q = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Song WHERE composer = :composer", composer="Lennon, John")
```

**source:** https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass

Comment: ah great! so the :1 notation is just saying that that is the first parameter listed after the GQL?

Answer (score 2):

parameters can be bound by position or name, look at the [GqlQuery](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass) class documentation for more info.

So you could do

```
personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from PersonalPost where user_id = :1 order by created desc limit 30", user_id)
```

or

```
personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from PersonalPost where user_id = :id order by created desc limit 30", id = user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a query like this:

```
query = PersonalPost.all()
query.filter('user_id', user_id)
query.order('-created')
```

or use: WITH single quotes around '%s'  !!

```
personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from PersonalPost where user_id = '%s' order by created desc" % user_id)
```

Comment: is either one of these technically better?  I can get both to work.  is one faster than the other?

Comment: I've tried this at the moment and you actually need to skip the single quotes now and just put %s then the variable after double quotes ends(no comma there also).